# How to write list elements to a text file without the brackets

Tags: python, list, csv, text-files, writer

I have many lists which I need to concatenate and print into a text file with headers. I have simplified the problem in the code below. What I want in the output text file is each header will have a number underneath it, I would like to be able to write the concatenated list but when I do the text file shows the list with brackets and commas).

**Code**

```
import csv

headers = ["emplyee ID","age","number of fish", "number of eyes","tentacles","spots"]
listA = [1102,33,17]
listB = [3,8,19]
output_list = listA + listB

results_filename = "my_results.txt"
filepath = ("/path/to/results/folder/")
results_file_path = filepath + results_filename
with open(results_file_path, 'w', newline='') as filey: 
    csv_writer = csv.writer(filey, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\r\n')
    csv_writer.writerow(["emplyee ID", "age", "number of fish", "number of eyes", "tentacles", "spots"])
filey.close()                                                                                                                                                                
      
                
with open(results_file_path, 'a', newline='') as filey: ## Python 3... with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(filey, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\r\n')
    #csv_writer.writerow([output_list])
    csv_writer.writerow([output_list[:]])
```

**Output**

[image]
**Desired output**

The contents of the list to be written to the text file so that the commas and brackets are not present and it can be read using the tab deliver.

Comment: Have you tried `csv_writer.writerow(output_list)` or `csv_writer.writerow(list(map(str, output_list)))`?

Comment: Can you post that as an answer @ForceBru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`writerow` can write any iterable of integers](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#writer-objects):

> A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for `Writer` objects

...so you can write the list directly:

```
csv_writer.writerow(output_list)
```

Comment: Thanks ForceBru, I see both methods work and produce the same result, is there an occasion where one method is preferable over the other?

Comment: If you're working with numbers or strings, they're the same. You could also write `writerow(map(str, output_list))` (without `list`) since all iterables are supported. However, the solution in the answer seems to be the cleanest and easiest to read.